# Interpolate nomad local variables in external file

Tags: hcl, nomad, hashicorp

In my job definition, I have the following template:

```
variables {
  environment = "staging"
}

...
    task "server" {
      template {
        data        = file("vars.env")
        destination = "secrets/file.env"
        env         = true
      }
...
```

And my `vars.env` have something like

```
ENVIRONMENT=${var.environment}
```

But the template doesn't get the interpolated string, only the raw text from the file.
Is there a way to tell nomad to use the local variables when parsing the `vars.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to resolving this could be to use the artifact stanza to download the vars.env file, and then reference the downloaded artifact from your template stanza. In doing do, with the "source" attribute instead of "data", the file's contents are passed to the template engine to be processed.

https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template#remote-template

Comment: Good point. It just seems too much work to have the file deployed somewhere instead of processing a local one :(

Comment: That is also a reason why I haven't done this yet myself. :)

Up until now, I've been using HEREDOC in my templates (instead of the file function like you've done in your example) with the data attribute, which does result in very long jobspec files. I'm considering using this method though by storing my config files in Git, and using the artifact stanza's ability to pull from there and template my values properly.

Comment: But can it be done with `source` instead of `data` without `remote template`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible.
Vars in file templates are not interpolated.